# Ruby define_method question

Tags: ruby

Im reading Metaprogramming in Ruby.

Here are two code snippets from the book:

```
my_var = "Success"

MyClass = Class.new do 
  puts "#{my_var} in the class definition!"
  define_method :my_method do
    puts "#{my_var} in the method!"
  end
end

MyClass.new.my_method

⇒ Success in the class definition!
  Success in the method!
```

and:

```
def define_methods
  shared = 0

  Kernel.send :define_method, :counter do
    shared
  end

  Kernel.send :define_method, :inc do |x|
    shared += x
  end
end

define_methods

counter # => 0 
inc(4) 
counter # => 4
```

I wonder why one doesnt have to use dynamic dispatch (use of Kernel.send) when defining the method in the first example while one has to use it in the second example.

I given it some thoughts but cant understand it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Module#define_method` is private. Private methods can only be called without a receiver. So, in the second example, you need to use reflection (i.e. `send`) to circumvent the access restrictions.

Note that the first example *still* uses dynamic dispatch. In fact, in Ruby, *everything* (except variable access and some builtin operators) uses dynamic dispatch.

Comment: "Private methods can only be called without a receiver." - so.. simply omit the receiver, then it's going to be an implicit receiver, and it works fine. see my answer. did I misunderstood something?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: the implicit receiver is `self`, but the author wants the receiver to be `Kernel`.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what the book says, it works without `Kernel.send`, you just need a context where the class for `self` is including `Kernel` - which is almost always the case.

for example, if you do this in the main scope, it's there:

```
irb(main):024:0> self.class.ancestors
=> [Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

So, using

```
  define_method :counter do
    shared
  end
```

works fine.

You only need that trick if within the current context `Kernel` is not included, e.g. if you're inside a plain `BasicObject`, or some user created descendant class.